# How to deterministically window observable sequence on deterministic trigger sequence

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Consider a case of `Observable.Window` chopping the source sequence on a trigger sequence that is synchronously derived from the source sequence. The simplest case would be the sequence chopping itself into windows of size 1 (as in `sequence.Window(sequence)`), but consider a minimally more complex example:

```
var source = Observable.Range(0,5);
source.Publish(ps =>
  ps.Window(ps.Where(n => n % 3 == 0))).Dump();
```

Here `a.Windows(b)` opens a new window for sequence `a` whenever `b` produces an item. In fact, in this sample both sequences produce the item at the same time. A `Window` implementation may

- (1) first receive an item from `a`, then receive `b` and close current window, so we'll see `{ { 0 }, { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4 } }` on output, or
- (2) first receive `b` and close window, then pass through an `a` to the newly opened window, in which case we would see `{ { }, { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }`). It may also
- (3) throw a coin and decide in each case--and this is what I must assume it does until I read a specification as to otherwise.

In fact, I am seeing the behavior (1) in LINQpad with System.Reactive 2.3.0-forever-beta.

My questions are,

1. Is the choice (1) documented anywhere? May I rely on it?
2. If no, and `Window` is non-deterministic even for sequences in a deterministic mutual observation ordering, then is there another way to window a sequence in a deterministic manner, closing window *strictly after* a value satisfied the given predicate?

Comment: It should remain deterministic - the order of subscription will affect the order in which the items are processed by attached the observables.

Comment: @Slugart: I _know_ that (3) cannot realistically be the case, if you mean that. Unfortunately, it can be deterministic only if it is specified as such. A behavior without a specification is an answer without a question.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you'll find that you can rely on this choice. Rx is written in a very functional programming style so given the same inputs you should always get the same outputs.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I am totally certain that they do not use a random number generator :) But _given the same inputs you should always get the same outputs_ should be also extended with _in the exact same version of the Rx library_. (3) is obviously not the case, but (1) and (2) are liable to change one into another (e. g. in the unlikely case Rx.NET is ever out of beta), if not explicitly documented otherwise. I cannot trust empiry here.

Comment: @kkm did someone ask you to guarantee this code for eternity? Write a unit test that checks the behaviour of Rx and don't release if it fails.

Comment: @Slugart: Don't ye dare teaching thy neighbour trust in [nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_demons)! For they are demons. And nasal.